# Детские вопросы к слову «забесплатно»

Tags: орфография, значение-слов, наречия, приставка

Есть такая передача — [*Мир забесплатно*](https://kino.tricolor.tv/series/watch/mir-zabesplatno-2020/).
Услышав это название, девочка (9 лет, третий класс) сразу спросила: почему слово пишется слитно (с этим разобрались; наречие *за/бес/пла́т/н/о*) и что оно означает (и с этим разобрались; = бесплатно)?

Последовали другие вопросы.
Что это за приставка такая (**за-**), которая новое слово создаёт, а его значения не изменяет? (Вот [тут](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0) посмотрели — ничего подходящего для наречий не нашли.)
Какие еще есть слова с этой приставкой, в которых она практически не меняет смысл? (Я вспомнила только два: даром — **за**даром, всегда — **за**всегда.)
Помогите нам, пожалуйста.

Comment: Заприметили, может быть?

Comment: Слова *"забесплатно"*, *"задаром"* Викисловарь маркирует как просторечные. На мой взгляд, их образование прозрачно: *купить, получить "за что-то"*, где *"что-то"* заменилось на *"бесплатно"* и *"даром"* соответственно и со временем склеилось с предлогом (приставки в основном и произошли от предлогов).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Из словаря Кузнецова: **ЗА, предлог**. 13. кого-что. Указывает на предмет, в обмен на который производится или приобретается что-л. Сделать за деньги. // **Указывает на цену, стоимость**, по которой приобретается или продаётся что-л. Купить туфли за двадцать рублей. Продать за полцены.

Также: ***За так.*** Даром, бесплатно.

2. Сочетание ***за так***  уже имеет оттенок просторечия, так как значение предлога избыточно.
3. Образование наречий ***задаром, забесплатно*** происходило по схеме, характерной для обычных наречий: долго – надолго, всюду – повсюду, куда – откуда.

Но в этих случаях приставка придавала слову новый оттенок значения, в то время как для слов  ***задаром, забесплатно*** значение не менялось, то есть приставка была избыточной (ненужной, "неправильной").

4. Таким образом, можно сказать, что именно приставка ЗА придает наречиям **просторечный характер**, так как не меняет их основного значения.

Comment: Ага! Спасибо, *Sharon*. А в наречиях *завсегда, запросто* и в глаголе *заприметить* тоже можно считать приставку излишней? Может, еще есть подобные словечки?

Comment: Решение подобной задачи проверяется по словарю. Полностью совпадают значения слов «всегда» и «завсегда». Там стоит пометка нар.-разг. Слова «приметить» и «заприметить» уже немного отличаются по смысловым оттенкам: заприметить – это отметить В СОЗНАНИИ, а не просто заметить, обратить внимание. Стилевая пометка одинаковая – разг.  У слова «просто» нейтральное значение а у «запросто» – разг. Эти  слова имеют сходное значение,  но у «запросто»  оно как бы усиленное.  Да и по области определения они далеко  не всегда заменяют друг друга. Таким образом, мы видим, что у каждой пары слов своя история.

Comment: Почему в названии "Мир забесплатно" используется просторечное слово? Думаю, что это стилевой прием  для привлечения внимания аудитории. В целом подобные вопросы и решения таких задач развивает внимание и повышает интерес к языку, и особенно замечательно, если эти вопросы задают дети. Других слов пока не вспомню. А вы что-то про нас забыли, заходите чаще...

Comment: Sharon, как всегда великолепный ответ!

Comment: Спасибо! Всегда приятна ваша высокая оценка.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к словам Сержа и благодарю Вас, *Sharon*, за дополнительные разъяснения. А *мы* подумали и нашли еще два, как *мне* кажется, подходящих слова: дорого — задорого, дёшево — задёшево.

Comment: Из словаря: ЗАДЁШЕВО, нареч. Разг. Дёшево, за невысокую цену. Продать, купить, уступить з.  ЗАДОРОГО, нареч. Разг. Очень дорого. Продать товар з.
Да, интересные слова вы нашли. Но если посмотреть в словаре, то можно увидеть, что приставка ЗА там не лишняя.  Она  придает усилительное значение наречию: задорого – это очень дорого. Да и задешево тоже обычно не продают, а уступают.  Откуда же здесь усилительное значение? Обобщенное значение приставки ЗА передают наречия сзади, позади, также предлог ЗА. Вот и получается, что задешево – это «запредельно» дешево.

Comment: И еще вопрос: почему многие наречия с приставкой ЗА имеют стилевую пометку «разг.»? Вероятно, предлог ЗА в исходом словосочетании не может управлять наречием так, как существительным (за что? за дешево), а это отклонение от грамматической правильности.  В то же время мы видим, что в вашем следующем вопросе (про текст Солженицына)  разговорное наречие задешево  используется и в публицистическом стиле (один из вариантов применения подобных слов).