# Много вопросов к предложению Солженицына

Tags: запятые, тире, управление, авторская-пунктуация, аббревиатуры

Предложение обнаружилось при разборе вопроса о приставке "за-" ([Детские вопросы к слову «забесплатно»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470535/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)).

Из [Нацкорпуса](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE):
Потапов был тот самый инженер, который признал на следствии, подписал в протоколе, подтвердил на суде, что он лично продал немцам **и притом задешево** *первенец* сталинских пятилеток *ДнепроГЭС*, правда **―** уже во взорванном состоянии. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

Нужно или не нужно обособлять "и притом задёшево" ?
Как объяснить постановку тире?

Попутно: правильно ли управление (*первенец*) и написание аббревиатуры (*ДнепроГЭС*)?

Answer (score 1):

*Потапов был тот самый инженер, который признал на следствии, подписал в протоколе, подтвердил на суде, что он **лично** продал немцам **и притом задешево** первенца сталинских пятилеток ДнепроГЭС, правда ― уже во взорванном состоянии.*

1. Отсутствие обособления оборота "и притом задешево" соответствует правилам: Не ставится запятая перед союзом «и притом», соединяющим однородные члены предложения.
   http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_244

Однородные обстоятельства: ***лично и притом задешево***. Обособление в принципе возможно, если считать союз И присоединительным, а не соединительным, но в этом предложении оно нежелательно. Здесь нет оснований как для семантического подчеркивания оборота, так и для вставочной интонации.

2. ***Правда*** ― вводное слово с уступительным значением и может обособляться тире. Но в данном предложении больше подходит такое оформление: *...он лично продал немцам и притом задешево первенца сталинских пятилеток Днепрогэс ― **правда, уже во взорванном состоянии.***
3. **ПЕРВЕНЕЦ**, **-нца**; м. 1. Первый, старший ребёнок. 2. чего или с опр. **То, что появилось или создано первым** по времени в ряду подобных. Первенцы первой пятилетки.

В словаре указана форма Р.п. *первенца*. Можно считать, что значение **одушевленности** будет соответствовать обоим значениям (основному и переносному). Раньше, возможно, были другие правила.

Пример: В 1912 году двадцатитрехлетний инженер заключил соглашение с акционерным обществом «Руссо-Балт» (Русско-Балтийского вагонного завода) ― стал главным конструктором авиационного цеха «Руссо-Балта», а в июне 1913-го уже показывал **своего первенца** ― «Русского витязя» императору Николаю II… [Олег Мраморнов, 2008]

4. **Днепрогэс.** Такое написание соответствует правила Розенталя § 25. Сложносокращенные слова и аббревиатуры (п.4) http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=29#pp29

Также это подтверждает **Грамота.ру**

Вопрос № 260913. Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно писать: Днепрогес или ДнепроГЭС.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: **Днепрогэс.**

Comment: Спа-а-сибо! Дело в том, что в некоторых изданиях оборот "и притом задёшево" обособлен и Днепрогэс пишется по-разному, а вот тире и "он лично продал... первенец" (а это ведь винительный падеж) имеются везде. Вот поэтому я вся и *обсомневалась*.

Comment: Про тире и обособление я написала – здесь возможны варианты. Если автор так написал – это его дело, но смотрится и читается не лучшим образом. Солженицына вроде бы НЕ СЧИТАЮТ образцом стилистики, но авторский вариант сохраняется. "Первенец" он считает неодушевленным, вот и ставит В.п., а не Р.п., но это вопрос спорный. Днепрогэс писали по-разному, но у Розенталя четкое правило на этот счет, Грамота также дала разъяснение.   Всё это причины того, что в разных изданиях можно встретить варианты: кто-то сохраняет авторскую орфографию и пунктуацию, а кто-то исправляет.

Comment: Еще немного по поводу "первенца".  Я не уверена, что в источниках можно найти точную информацию  об одушевленности или неодушевленности слова  в переносном значении. Но само сочетание "продал первенец" совершенно неприемлемо на слух, и писатель мог бы об этом подумать. Дело в том, что обычно это слово используется в прямом значении.